# Array of arrays of string correct declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need an array of arrays of string in my programm. I am declaring it so:

```
string edges[N][N] = {
{"0", "A", "0", "B", "E", "0", "0", "P1", "0"},
{"A", "0", "D", "I", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "D", "0", "0", "0", "H", "F", "0", "0"},
{"B", "I", "0", "0", "0", "H", "0", "0", "0"},
{"E", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "P2", "0"},
{"0", "0", "H", "H", "0", "0", "0", "0", "P4"},
{"0", "0", "F", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "P3"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
};
```

Its okay, when I am trying to access strings with 1-letter value (A or B etc), but If I try to access string with 2-letters value, like `edges[0, 7]` (value is "P1"), programm will output 0. What's wrong?
It working fine if element is 1-letter like A, B, C, etc, but fail with P1 or P2.
Full programm listing and working programm is here http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE

Comment: "strings which are chars"? There is no such thing. Do you means strings that are only one character long (not counting the null terminator)?

Comment: Don't you mean `edges[0][7]`? `edges[0, 7]` is the same as `edges[7]`.

Comment: @Angew I meant `edges[0][7]`. Sorry. @ValekHalfHeart, sorry for my bad english, I eddited my question.

Comment: Your counting is off... remember that the first element in an array is `[0]`, so `edges[0][8]` in an array of `[9][9]` is the last entry on the first line... "0".  The same thing in your program on ideone... the indices you're printing are legitimately "0" elements in your array.  See http://ideone.com/OywUMI

Comment: I edited my question yet. I failed with index. I am trying to access not-zero element. Index is [0, 7]. `Distance to N1: 6; Path: R4 -(B)-> R1 : 3 : 0 -(0)-> N1 : 0 : 7`. I eddited my code, so indexes are printing too. Look, they are correct.

Comment: In your edited code, `cout << " -(" << edges[next][prev] << ")-> " << names[tmp] << " : " << prev << " : " << next;` <-- note you print `prev` before `next`, but you index in the opposite order.  If you look up `[next][prev]` e.g. `[8][5]` you'll find they *are* "0".

Comment: @TonyD Oops! As Always - devil is in the details! Thank you very much. It is working now!

Answer (score 1):

He Here's show value 0 in position [0,8], so, it's correct. well, it's correct.
Array's going to arrange follow:

```
string edges[N][N] = {
{[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5], [0,6], [0,7], [0,8]},
  ....
[8,0], [8,1], [8,2], [8,3], [8,4], [8,5], [8,6], [8,7], [8,8]}}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want 7, not 8.  C languages us a 0 index.

Comment: Oops. Sure it is `edges[0, 7]`, sorry. Edited.